# caffe, Train model with python layer got an error

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I try to run the linreg example in /examples/pycaffe.

I added a solver.prototxt for it.

Then I try to train it, but I got an error.

Can you help me?

**the solver.prototxt I added:**

```
net: "${caffe_dir}/examples/pycaffe/linreg.prototxt"
display: 40
base_lr: 0.1
lr_policy: "step"
stepsize: 320000
gamma: 0.96
max_iter: 600000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0001
snapshot: 40000
snapshot_prefix: "test"
solver_mode: CPU
```

**the error info is:**

`I0815 19:23:26.105624  7281 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
*** Aborted at 1502796212 (unix time) try "date -d @1502796212" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f6713ded458 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 7281 (TID 0x7f671559aa40) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f6712fd9cb0 (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713ded458 (unknown)
    @     0x7f66ce27bd40 google::protobuf::python::message_meta::AddFieldNumberToClass()
    @     0x7f66ce27c1e6 google::protobuf::python::message_meta::New()
    @     0x7f6713699953 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136970a3 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136be2d6 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2c3d (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2f22 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c377c (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713726ef6 (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713727609 (unknown)
    @     0x7f671362747f (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713720a46 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136f485f (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136970a3 (unknown)
    @     0x7f671372a5f7 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136be6d3 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2c3d (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2f22 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c377c (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713726ef6 (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713727609 (unknown)
    @     0x7f671362747f (unknown)
    @     0x7f6713720a46 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136f485f (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136970a3 (unknown)
    @     0x7f671372a5f7 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136be6d3 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2c3d (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c2f22 (unknown)
    @     0x7f67136c377c (unknown)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail. 
this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail.
this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail.
this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail.
this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail.
this sentence has no sense. It's just a tail.

Answer (score 1):

solved !

That's because the python-protobuf's version is 3.2.0, but the protobuf installed by `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev` is 2.5.0 version.

So, make the two have same version can solve this problem.